# Convert modelform dropdown field into textfield

Tags: jquery, django

What I want to do is when a user want to edit, he/she should be able to see the PlotID in textfield format not dropdown format, because for right now the Plot_ID field is displayed as dropdown not textfield.

What I want to do is when a user want to edit, he/she should be able to see the PlotID in textfield format not dropdown format, because for right now the Plot_ID field is displayed as dropdown not textfield.

My model.py:

```
class Farm(models.Model):
    farmID = models.CharField('farmID',primary_key=True, max_length=20)
    fieldsize = models.FloatField('Field Size (hactre)')

class Plot(models.Model):
    farm = models.ForeignKey(Farm,verbose_name='FarmID')
    plotID = models.CharField('PlotID',max_length=50)

class PlotManagement(models.Model):
    farm = models.ForeignKey(Farm,verbose_name='FieldID')
    plotID = models.ForeignKey(Plot,verbose_name='PlotID')
```

My form.py

```
class PlotManagementForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model=PlotManagement
        exclude=('enteredpersonel',)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PlotManagementForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['farm'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['plotID'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```

my template.html:
    
    {{ plotmanagementform.farm.errors }}
    Farmer:
    
    {{ plotmanagementform.farm }}

```
<div class="form-group"> 
{{ plotmanagementform.plotID.errors }}
<label for="plotID" class="col-md-4 control-label">Plot ID:</label>
<div class="col-md-4 selectContainer">
{{ plotmanagementform.plotID }}
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? its going to be very hard for your users to actually know what the id of a particular plot instance is

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for select2 without even knowing it? Check it out just in case. https://select2.github.io/examples.html

Comment: what i want to do is quite different compared to select2; what i want is to have a textfield where a user can enter their field without the dropdown

Comment: I have javascript code that pop up name instead of ID @Sayse

Comment: my views.py looks:
    def edit_farmer_detail(request,plotID,personID):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('signup:login'))
    if request.method == 'POST': 
    plotmanagementform = PlotManagementForm(request.POST)
    if plotmanagementform.is_valid():
    plotID = plotmanagementform.cleaned_data['plotID']
    return 
    else:
    plotmanagement_instance = PlotManagement.objects.get(farm=personID,plotID=Plot.objects.get(plotID=plotID,farm=personID))
    plotmanagementform = PlotManagementForm(instance = plotmanagement_instance)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the widget of the PlotId field to a TextInput like this:

`self.fields['plotID'].widget = TextInput()`

You will have to import `TextInput` from `django.forms.widgets` . Or perhaps a `NumberInput()` would be more appropriate here.

**But as mentioned in comments, doing this is not a good idea.** It's not a good idea to make a primary or foreign key ID editable because your database and relations can easily go out of sync if you make a mistake.